# Running time calculation in multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, runnable

In my code:

```
public class thread1 implements Runnable {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    thread1 d = new thread1();
    new Thread(d).start();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(d);
    t1.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        sleep1();
        sleep2();
    }
}

void sleep1() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

synchronized void sleep2() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I ran my code and calculate its running time to finished.

The minimum time to finished was `7` seconds.

Why?

It should be 6 seconds, Because 
`3loops * 2seconds = 6seconds`.

Comment: what about the time for context switching and other "maintainance activities"?.. You should  worry if the time taken is less than 6 seconds. BTW you shouldn't measure time in this way..

Comment: How were you measuring the time?

Comment: @KarolS So simple, just run it in my IDE and see to my watch!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of context switching. sleep() is not a guaranteed amount of time, but is subject to other things going on in the system. It will try to come back, but may not succeed. Also, probably rounding in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Program running time also accountable. You have put 6 secs to thread sleep. So Next thread will be executed. So context switching takes place.